# For Python 3, how do I import a .py file from another directory?

Tags: python, import, python-import

I'm running Window 10 64-bit. I have a Python project:

```
A:\code\projectFolder\project.py
```

For project.py, I want to import the following file:

```
A:\code\importThisFolder\importThisFile.py
```

On project.py, I've tried using without success:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'A:\code\importThisFolder')
import importThisFile
```

Can someone please help me with my import issues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: I've read that question before I posted my own question. I've used the sys.path.insert() method with no success.

Comment: Your backslaches (`'\'`) could be the issue. Use `r'A:\code\importThisFolder'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looks like I had a mispelling and accidently used the wrong backslash. The appropriate backslash is '\'. I accidently used '/'. Thanks @busybear !

Answer (score 0):

the simple solution is to put both file in same directory and then just write import thisfile or from thisfile import file.

if you put both script in same folder then it won't create any issue.

Answer (score -1):

Don't. Simply move both .py files to the same directory and simply use:

```
import my_file
```

Alternatively, you can move your .py file to your site-packages folder.

Comment: Not only this is not always possible, but it is also undesirable if the module is a part of another project.